# Confusion related to broken authentication vulnerability

Tags: authentication, web-application

I was able to login by using the cookie of my previous session but when I try to change the setting I was logged out. Will this be eligible for authentication bypass vulnerability?

Answer (score 0):

In and of itself, no. Simply showing that a session cookie expiration is set too long doesn't mean that there aren't other mechanisms to prevent you hijacking someone else's session.

Best practice for sessions is to invalidate on logout, and after a given period of time(since most people just close tabs without hitting 'logout'). Now, if you hit 'logout' and then you are able to reconnect to the session with the previously saved session key, that's it's own issue (I actually saw a site do session termination by clearing the cookie on the client, but not invalidating it server-side... and session IDs were incrementing).

If you want to test this for auth bypass/session hijacking, create a separate account, log in on another machine/browser/etc, and copy *that* session cookie over. If you are then authenticated as that session/user, it is a confirmed auth bypass/hijack.

Comment: I am able to login from different machine but when I try to change the setting then it ask for password. So it will be eligible for bounty?

Comment: It sounds more *likely* (assuming that by 'login' you meant manually adding the cookie and not actually logging in), but I would recommend putting together a more complete set of tests before you submit this; if you went to most companies with only what you've posted here, they probably wouldn't consider it sufficient for a bounty.